# create a poor map with lidars

Tags: navigation, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I encountered a problem using the Lidar to create the map. Map is not closed.
I am using the Gmapping method.

[image: map]

Does anyone know why this is? Or give me some advice? Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/276226/create-a-poor-map-with-lidars/) by [vic_zhu](https://answers.ros.org/users/32681/vic_zhu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-11-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To me it looks like the laser scanner is working well, but the ODOM drift is too high, so the robot loses it's sense of direction over time.
Can I assume your robot has wheel encoders?
If it does, you should redo the calibration, especially for encoder counts on each wheel during rotating.
If your odom is based on a calculation of counts and wheel measurements, I suggest instead you determine the counts/meter and counts/radian through measurement instead of calculating. See section 1.2 of this: http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/Navigation%20Tuning%20Guide
Once you are confident in the calibration, remap and make sure any rotation during mapping is done very slowly.

---

Originally posted by [billy](https://answers.ros.org/users/26871/billy/) with karma: 1850 on 2017-11-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0